# HAA0502 Explicit new reference type allocation

Tags: c#, clr, heap-memory, asp.net-core-2.1

I have `ASP.Net Core 2.1`, `C#` application. I am using **Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MukulSabharwal.ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer

One of the methods looks as below

Ex#1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

services.AddSingleton<IPocoDynamo>(serviceProvider => {
    var pocoDynamo = new PocoDynamo(serviceProvider.GetRequieredService<IAmazonDynamoDB>());
    pocoDynamo.SomeMethod();
    return pocoDynamo;
});
```

}

Ex.#2

```
public async Task<EventTO> AddEvent(EventTO eventObj)
{
  try
    {       
      throw new Exception("Error!");
    }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Logger.Log(ex, eventObj);
   return null;
  }
}
```

I am using DI throughout the app. But wherever the analyzer is finding `new` keyword thing, it is warning as

> HAA0502   Explicit new reference type allocation

Also wherever Lambda expression is used, it is warning as (like in ex#1)

```
Warning HAA0301 Heap allocation of closure Captures:
```

What is causing this & how to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that HAA0502 is trying to encourage you to use factory methods that may cache and re-use objects. HAA0301 is trying to warn you that a closure object is being allocated to provide access to locals with a scope broader than the lambda expression. Many methods that take a delegate will also allow you to pass in an argument, which might allow you to avoid such an allocation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? The analyzer you use is supposed to show the warning for each `new` statement for reference types, as well as (in most cases) for lambdas. What is unclear to you?

Answer (score 3):

**Heap Allocation Analyzer** is used to mark all the allocations your code performs. This is not something you would like to have always on: consider the following silly code

```cs
        public static string MyToString(object? o)
        {
            if (o == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o)); // HAA0502 here

            return o.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
```

The analyzer will emit HAA0502 in the form of *warning as information* on the marked line to tell you that you are allocating a new instance. Now, it is obvious in this case what you are doing, and it is a trivial warning, but the purpose of the analyzer is to help you spot nasty allocations that might turn your code into something slower.

Now consider this silly code here:

```cs
        public static void Test1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var a = i + 1;

                var action = new Action(
                    () =>   // HAA0301 Heap allocation of closure Capture: a
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(a);
                    }
                );

                action();
            }
        }
```

Other than HAA0502 which will be marked on `new Action(` because we are creating a new object, there is an additional warning on the lambda: **HAA0301**. This is why the analyzer gets more useful: here the analyzer is telling you that the runtime will create a new object containing your captured variable `a`. If you are not familiar with this, you may think at that code to get transformed in something like this (for explanatory purposes only):

```cs
        private sealed class Temp1
        {
            public int Value1 { get; }

            public Temp1(int value1)
            {
                Value1 = value1;
            }

            public void Method1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Value1);
            }
        }

        public static void Test1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var a = i + 1;

                var t = new Temp1(a);
                t.Method1();
            }
        }
```

In the latter code, it becomes evident that at every iteration you are allocating an object.

The main question you may have is: **is allocating an object a problem?** In 99.9% of the cases it is not a problem and you may embrace the simplicity of writing readable, precise and concise code without dealing with low level details, **but** if you are caught in performance issues (i.e. the remaining 0.01%), the analyzer can get quite handy as it shows in one shots where you **or the compiler in your behalf** is allocating something. Allocating objects require a future garbage collector cycle to reclaim the memory.

Regarding your code, you are initializing a service via DI with the factory pattern: that code runs once. Therefore there is no surprise you are allocating a new object. So you can safely suppress the warning on this portion of code. You may use the IDE to let generate the suppression code. This is why I suggest to keep the analyzer disabled and enable it only when hunting performance problems.